# Tratamento de exceção não funcionando

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Olá, estou estudando C# e estava tentando fazer tratamento de exceção usando middleware, para enviar a mensagem e o código da exceção para o client, porém não está dando muito certo.

Debugando, o breakpoint está passando normalmente no middleware, porém não está enviando o erro para o client. O código do middleware é este:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
        {
            errorApp.Run(async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

                if (error != null)
                {
                    var ex = error.Error;

                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDto()
                    {
                        StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                        Message = ex.Message
                    }.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
                }
            });
        });

public class ErrorDto
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

e meu Startup.cs está assim:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseCors("Desenvolvimento");
        else
            app.UseHsts();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.ExceptionHandler();

        app.UseMvc(opts =>
        {
            opts.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Não seria `app.UseExceptionHandler()`?

Answer (score -1):

Para criar um Middleware de exception, estou usando esse tratamento aqui

Crie uma classe middleware

```
     public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
        {
            private readonly RequestDelegate next;

            public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
            {
                this.next = next;
            }

// nesse Invoke eh possivel injetar qualquer coisa
            public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
            {
                try
                {
                    await next(context);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
//Capture o erro aqui
                    await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
                }
            }

//Trate o erro aqui
            private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
            {
                var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected
                var result = string.Empty; // coloque qualquer coisa aqui

                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(result); // retorne o objeto como json.
            }
        }
```

Depois adicione a classe no seu configure no Startup.cs

```
//Startup.cs

public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
            {
               // seu codigo aqui

                app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

             //Antes de app.UseMvc();
                app.UseMvc();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

No asp.net core você trata isso em "filters". Crie uma classe que implementa a interface "IExceptionFilter". Nela você pode usar o context para realizar todo o tratamento, você também pode injetar normalmente o que precisar no construtor. Exemplo:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace Exemplo1.API.Infrastructure.Filters
{
    public class HttpGlobalExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;
        private readonly ILogger<HttpGlobalExceptionFilter> logger;

        public HttpGlobalExceptionFilter(IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<HttpGlobalExceptionFilter> logger)
        {
            this.env = env;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            logger.LogError(new EventId(context.Exception.HResult),
                context.Exception,
                context.Exception.Message);

            var json = new JsonErrorResponse
            {
                Messages = new[] { "Ocorreu um erro. Tente novamente." }
            };

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                json.DeveloperMessage = context.Exception;
            }

            // Result asigned to a result object but in destiny the response is empty. This is a known bug of .net core 1.1
            // It will be fixed in .net core 1.1.2. See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5594 for more information
            context.Result = new InternalServerErrorObjectResult(json);
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }

        private class JsonErrorResponse
        {
            public string[] Messages { get; set; }

            public object DeveloperMessage { get; set; }
        }

    }

    public class InternalServerErrorObjectResult : ObjectResult
    {
        public InternalServerErrorObjectResult(object error)
            : base(error)
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
        }
    }
}
```

Depois é só adicionar no startup:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(HttpGlobalExceptionFilter));
        })
```

Para saber quais filtros são disponibilizados e em que momento eles são executados no pipeline do asp.net core, você pode acessar o seguinte link:

[Filtros no ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2)